# ffmpeg is killed

Tags: x11, ffmpeg

So I have a problem here. I have a session of `ffmpeg -f x11grab` running, and suddenly `kill -9` or `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` comes and GUI dies of course. So far everything seems to be OK.

When I try to play the file `ffmpeg` was writing to with `ffplay` I got:

> invalid data found when processing input

How could I solve it? I need to have this file readable.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you send SIGKILL? That's a very poor idea, it gives no time for ffmpeg to close the file or do any cleanup work (SIGKILL is untrappable). you almost never want `kill -9`.

Comment: @ChrisDown It's actually not a `kill -9` but just `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`, which I supposed should initiate `kill -9`. You shouldn't tell me that's a bad idea, I totally understand, but that's not me that sends the signal.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that ffmpeg didn't close the stream. You can simply process this file with ffpeg or mencoder, copying its contents without recoding to new file. Something like

```
mencoder file.mp4 -oac copy -ovc copy -o newfile.mp4
```

Comment: This doesn't help unfortunately